# Printing images with pHp

Tags: php, pdf, printing, web

I have a php website in which the user can browse between documents. These documents are like PDFs but converted into PNG files to make it work on mobiles. My question is, is there a way I can make a Printer dialog in pHp in which the user could choose the printings options that a "normal" printer dialog can offer ?

Thanks

Comment: what issue are you trying to solve? what's wrong with the clients own printer dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You cannot change this behavior of the client.